# Count uppercase, lowercase, digits, and whitespace in file

Tags: python, count, character, uppercase

I'm tasked with counting uppercase, lowercase, digits, and whitespace characters in a `.txt` file.

I've tried it a variety of ways and I can't quite seem to get it right. I can't figure out where I'm off.

Here's the output that I get:

The uppercase count is 0
The lowercase count is 0
The digit count is 0
The whitespace count is 0

Code:

```
def main():

    uppercase_count = 0
    lowercase_count = 0
    digits_count = 0
    whitespace_count = 0

    uppercase =['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
    lowercase = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    digits = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    whitespace = [' ']

    infile = open("text.txt", "r")

    data = infile.readlines()

    for character in data:
        if character in uppercase:
            uppercase_count += 1

    for character in data:
        if character in lowercase:
            lowercase_count += 1

    for character in data:
        if character in digits:
            digits_count += 1

    for character in data:
        if character in whitespace:
            whitespace_count += 1

    print('The uppercase count is',uppercase_count)
    print('The lowercase count is',lowercase_count)
    print('The digit count is',digits_count)
    print('The whitespace count is',whitespace_count)

main()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use built in fuctions

```
for character in data:
    if character.isupper():
        uppercase_count += 1
    elif character.islower():
        lowercase_count += 1
    elif character.isspace():
        whitespace_count +=1
    elif character.isdigit():
        digit_count +=1
```

Also may be you could use the following to have each line get counted for characters.

```
digit_count,whitespace_count,lowercase_count,uppercase_count=0,0,0,0
lines = infile.readlines()
for data in lines:
    for character in data:
        if character.isupper():
            uppercase_count += 1
        elif character.islower():
            lowercase_count += 1
        elif character.isspace():
            whitespace_count +=1
        elif character.isdigit():
            digit_count +=1
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading line by line, not by `char`, so you read it as a whole string through `read`, plus it's better to group all your `for` loops into one, this way:

```
data = infile.read()

for character in data:
    if character in uppercase:
        uppercase_count += 1

    elif character in lowercase:
        lowercase_count += 1

    elif character in digits:
        digits_count += 1


    elif character in whitespace:
        whitespace_count += 1
```

EDIT:

Also, there is no reason for you to store all `upper-case`, `lower-case`, `digits` and `white space` characters in lists like you did, use the `string` module, which has all of these already ready:

```
>>> string.uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\x8a\x8c\x8e\x9f\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde'
>>> string.lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\x83\x9a\x9c\x9e\xaa\xb5\xba\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
>>> string.whitespace
'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '
```

A better approach is to use built-in methods:

isupper(), islower() .. which you can check for them [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

Comment: Or may be use built in functions like isspace, islower, isupper, isdigit

Answer (score 1):

```
data = infile.read()
```

Do not read `lines` but read the file as a whole string.Of you read lines `character` will be a `line` but you want it to be `character`

Answer (score 1):

```
data = infile.read()
value = [ i for i in data]
upper = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.isupper(), value)))
digit = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), value)))
space = len(list(filter(lambda x: x.isspace(), value)))
```

Comment: You may have the right answer but please also provide some explanation of your code.